# PHP - aгрегация диапазонов номеров телефона

Tags: php, массивы, сравнение, числа

Есть диапазон номеров. Пример:

3420000000 - 3429999999

3423333333 - 3424444444

3432111111 - 3433333333

3432000000 - 3433311111

и так далее...
Как в PHP сделать merge - схлопнуть диапазоны, которые входят в больший диапазон и оставить только самые крупные?
Я додумался только до сравнения: берем 3423333333 и сравниваем с 3429999999, потом 3424444444 сравниваем с 3429999999. Если 3423333333 < 3429999999 и 3424444444 < 3429999999, то он входит в первый диапазон 3420000000 - 3429999999. 
Это все нужно делать в массиве. Помоему мое решение какое-то убогое и не эффективное.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать. Покажите пример того, что должно получиться.

Comment: В итоге остаются только самые большие диапазоны, включающие в себя остальные.
3420000000 - 3429999999


3432111111 - 3433333333

Comment: Без просмотра всех диапазонов задачу не решить

Comment: можете начать с самых коротких, чтоб меньше итераций делать :)

Comment: Ну элементарная же ж задачка! Всего-то и надо, что отсортировать массив диапазонов по возрастанию начал, и потом один раз пройти по нему, сливая итоги наложения в выходной массив.

Comment: А какой функцией делать наложение?

Comment: Два вопроса: 1) если диапазоны примыкают (`1 - 5`, `6 - 9`) что должно получится в итоге? И если пересекаются (`1 - 7`, `4 - 9`')

Comment: должно получится (1-5, 6-9) и (1 -7, 4-9).  6-9 не входит в диапазон 1-5 и  4-9 не входит в 1-7